# Api to access Conversation History and In Place Hold for Office 365

Tags: ms-office, office365

We are trying to access the Conversation History in Office 365 for accessing the chat history.We are using the Rest Apis provided in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/API-catalog#Outlookmail . However , we are unable to get the folder id of the folder Conversation History . As a result , we are not able to fetch the mails under Conversation History. Is there a way to get access to the chat history under the folder "Conversation History ?

We are also , interested to get the data for chats which might be deleted by mistake by the users from Conversation History. Hence , we are looking for getting the data for in place hold users as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/folders/ConversationHistory/Messages to get the messages in ConversationHistory folder.  For well known folder names (Inbox, DeletedItems, ConversationHistory etc.), we allow you to specify the folder ID or the well known name.  The response always refers to the folder using the folder ID.  We will look into why https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/folders/ConversationHistory is failing.

Comment: Thanks Venkat . This solves our problem. Regarding the in place hold content , do you have similar rest apis , or is there a seperate way to do that? Thanks again for the above help..